# Good or bad practice: passing parameter by value when you will have to modify it?

Tags: c++

Consider this function:

```
bool doSomething( const std::string& str );
```

It takes a `std::string` by reference as it does not modify it. OK.

Now, let's suppose that the function needs to modify the parameter as pre-processing in order to get its decision and return:

```
bool doSomething( const std::string& str )
{
    std::string copy = str;
    // preprocessing: modify copy 
    return copy.size(); // or anything else, where test on copy
                        // is different than test on str 
                        // due to preprocessing operation
}
```

Often, when I have this, I prefer to change the function prototype to `bool doSomething( std::string str )`. I like it because it prevents bugs where developer (me) could accidentally use `str` instead of `copy` in the function implementation...(it happened in the past).

But people reading my header file will often say, *"Hey, why are you passing this object by copy, not by const reference, that's bad...?"*.

Question: is passing by copy in this specific case (where the function will for sure do a copy internally) a good or bad practice?

Comment: @melak47: can you provide a link to herb sutter's talk ?

Comment: @Destructor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64 There are some reference in this talk.

Comment: The talk is also linked in the answer to the question this one is a duplicate of :)

Comment: @all: Sorry for the duplicate...

Comment: I would say good.  I do it all the time now.  It allows return value optimisation too I believe.